# GCP App Engine Custom Runtime Image location

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-container-registry

I have create an app engine in gcp which uses a custom runtime. And I could see that the resources(docker images) getting uploaded to the cloud storage bucket. But I cannot see the image in container registry or artifact registry even after enabling the respective apis.

does custom runtime in gcp uses only cloud storage to store the image or do I have to make any configuration to store the image to the container or artifact registry?